# Помогите написать такую же функцию используя метод bind в setTimeout

Tags: javascript

есть функция, которая выводит от 0 до 9

```
function counter() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

нужно написать такую же используя метод bind в setTimeout

Помогите пожалуйста!!!!

Comment: а в чем у вас трудность?
Извините, но домашнее задание сделайте самостоятельно

Comment: Как пытались это реализовать вы и что не получается?

Comment: А нафига тут bind?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы привязать контекст к функции используется встроенный метод **bind**

> **Метод .bind(context)** принимает на вход объект, который устанавливается как контекст(**this**) для возвращаемой функции.

```js
const fn = function (a, b) {
    console.log(this);
}
   
const fnNew = fn.bind({a: 1, b: 2});
fnNew();
```

> Так же методом bind можно привязать аргументы новой функции. Синтаксис bind(context, arg1, arg2, ... argN);

```js
const fn = function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
const fnNew = fn.bind(null, 4);
console.log(fnNew(2));
```

Для того, что бы реализовать вывод значений в setTimeout с использованием метода .bind() нам потребуется создать вспомогательную функцию.

```js
function counter() {
  // Создаем функцию print, которая будет выводить переданное значение через метод bind
  function print () {
console.log(this.i);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
// Т.к. метод bind возвращает нам новую функцию,
// ее можно сразу передать в setTimeout
setTimeout(print.bind({i: i}), 100);
  }
}

counter();
```