# Как сделать сортировку таблицы по нажатию на столбец?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такая таблица

```
<table style="text-align:center" id="my_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th>Факультет</th>
            <th>Дата рождения</th>
            <th>Год начала обучения</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Как реализовать ее сортировку по нажатию на столбец, например фио и факультет по алфавиту?

Значения таблицы хранятся в массиве типа

```
 cosnt arr = [{surname: 'Арзамасцев', name: 'Николай', middle_name: 'Николаевич', bornded: '03.03.2001', start_study: '2019', fac: 'Информатика и вычислительная техника' }]
```

Отрисовывется таблица через фукнцию:

```
buildTable(arr_info)
function buildTable(data) {
    let table = document.getElementById('table')
    let today = new Date()
    let todayYear = today.getFullYear()
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let fioObj = data[i].surname + "\n" + data[i].name + "\n" + data[i].middle_name;
        let old = age(data[i].bornded);
        let course = find_end_study(data[i].start_study)
        let row = `
        <tr>
        <td>${fioObj}</td>
        <td>${data[i].fac}</td>
        <td>${data[i].bornded} (${old})</td>
        <td>${data[i].start_study}-${todayYear} (${course})</td>
        <tr/>
        `
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}
```

Comment: Как хранятся данные таблицы, как они отрисовываются? Какой формат данных?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/4419684

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Реализуем сортировку таблицы по нажатию на столбец с помощью JavaScript

Рассмотрим следующую *userStory* от заказчика:

> Я, как пользователь, хочу, что бы при нажатии на название столбца, происходила сортировка значений по данному столбцу. При повторном нажатии, сортировка происходила в обратной последовательности.

Декомпозируем задачу исходя из требований:

- Нужен обработчик события нажатия на заголовок таблицы
- Нужна функция сортировки данных по заданному столбцу.
- Нужна универсальная функция рендера(отрисовки) таблицы

Реализуем последовательно все требования:

Собираем все наши заголовки(допустим методом **getElementsByTagName**) таблицы и вешаем обработчик события

```
const header = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for (let i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    header[i].addEventListener('click', order);
}
```

Мы назначили событию **click** функцию обработчик **order**. Подробнее о [добавлении и удалении событий DOM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dom/1453302#1453302)

Функция **order** принимает в себя значение клика мыши в виде DOM элемента, на котором данное событие было осуществлено.

```
function order(e) {
    
    switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'fio':
            selectOrd(e.target.id);
            arr = arr.sort(sorterName);             
            break;
        default:
            selectOrd(e.target.id);
            const sortBnd = sortString.bind({orderBy: e.target.id});
            arr = arr.sort(sortBnd);                
    }
    buildTable(arr);
}
```

Данная функция будет проверять ID элемента и вызывать соответствующую функцию сортировки данных, после сортировки вызывать функцию buildTable для отрисовки результата.

Стоит обратить внимание, что для того, что бы не описывать каждую функцию сортировки отдельно, [используется метод .bind()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453783/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-bind-%d0%b2-settimeout/1453871#1453871).

Отдельно нам потребуется хранить текущий порядок сортировки и поле, по которому осуществляется сортировка

```
// Порядок сортировки
let ordASC = 1;
// Сортируемое поле
let ordField = 'fio';
```

Что бы не дублировать себя, вынесем изменение данных значений в отдельную функцию:

```
function selectOrd(id) {
    if (id === ordField) {
        ordASC *= -1;
    } else {
        ordField = id;
        ordASC = 1;
    }
}
```

Основные моменты выполнены, осталось все это совместить. Ниже полный код для 1 статической таблицы(из вопроса).

```js
/**
 * Тип данных для студента
 * @typedef {Object} StudentType
 * @property {string} surname
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} middle_name
 * @property {string} bornded
 * @property {string} start_study
 * @property {string} fac
 */
//Список студентов
/** @type {StudentType[]} */
let arr = [
    {
        surname: 'Арзамасцев',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.2001',
        start_study: '2019',
        fac: 'Информатика и вычислительная техника'
    },
    {
        surname: 'Иванов',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.2000',
        start_study: '2018',
        fac: 'экономика'
    },
    {
        surname: 'Петров',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.1999',
        start_study: '2020',
        fac: 'Юрист'
    },
    {
        surname: 'Ягоднкина',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.2003',
        start_study: '2017',
        fac: 'торговец'
    },
    {
        surname: 'Малинкина',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.1998',
        start_study: '2021',
        fac: 'Бизнесмен'
    },
    {
        surname: 'Клюкова',
        name: 'Николай',
        middle_name: 'Николаевич',
        bornded: '03.03.2002',
        start_study: '2016',
        fac: 'не работает'
    },
];
// Порядок сортировки
let ordASC = 1;
// Сортируемое поле
let ordField = '';

/**
 * Функция возвращает полное имя студента
 * @param {StudentType} student
 * @return {string}
 * */
function getFullName(student) {
    return student.surname + "\n" + student.name + "\n" + student.middle_name;
}

/**
 * Функция сортировки для таблицы
 * @param {StudentType} a
 * @param {StudentType} b
 * @return {number}
 */
function sorterName(a, b) {
    return getFullName(a).localeCompare(getFullName(b)) * ordASC;
}

/**
 * Функция сортировки для таблицы
 * @param {StudentType} a
 * @param {StudentType} b
 * @return {number}
 */
function sortString(a, b) {
    return a[this.orderBy].localeCompare(b[this.orderBy]) * ordASC;
}

/** @param {string} id */
function selectOrd(id) {
    if (id === ordField) {
        ordASC *= -1;
    } else {
        ordField = id;
        ordASC = 1;
    }
}
/** @param {PointerEvent} e */
function order(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.id) {
        switch (e.target.id) {
            case 'fio':
                selectOrd(e.target.id);
                arr = arr.sort(sorterName);                    
                break;
            default:
                selectOrd(e.target.id);
                const sortBnd = sortString.bind({orderBy: e.target.id});
                arr = arr.sort(sortBnd);                    
        }
        buildTable(arr);
    }
}

const header = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for (let i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    header[i].addEventListener('click', order);
}

/** @param {StudentType[]} data */
function buildTable(data) {
    let table = document.getElementById('table')
    table.innerHTML = '';
    let today = new Date()
    let todayYear = today.getFullYear()
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let fioObj = getFullName(data[i]);
        let old = data[i].bornded;//age(data[i].bornded);
        let course = data[i].start_study; //find_end_study(data[i].start_study)
        let row = `
            <tr>
                <td>${fioObj}</td>
                <td>${data[i].fac}</td>
                <td>${data[i].bornded} (${old})</td>
                <td>${data[i].start_study}-${todayYear} (${course})</td>
            <tr/>
            `;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
}

buildTable(arr);
```

```html
<table style="text-align:center" id="my_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th id="fio">ФИО</th>
    <th id="fac">Факультет</th>
    <th id="bornded">Дата рождения</th>
    <th id="start_study">Год начала обучения</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>
```