# Можно ли менять положение элементов страницы с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, веб-программирование

Допустим, я беру данные из бд и с помощью django передаю их в html страницу, допустим у меня список товаров. И я хочу реализовать несколько кнопок для сортировки товаров по параметру, допустим выбираю параметр 'по цене' и js перестраивает мою страницу

Comment: Да, такое возможно, силами javaScript. Кстити, вот пример [таблицы с сортировкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461333/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%86/1462176#1462176)

Comment: Если при этом будете использовать vue.js, то сортировка будет сводиться к сортировке коллекции/массива, т.е. без необходимости прямого манипулирования HTML-элементами.

Comment: можно, проще всего parent: display: flex; children: order: number of order. только вот кто сортирует на фронте? что за задача такая интерестная?